# Google Analytics: exclude with regex

Tags: regex, google-analytics

Although my regular expression works on regexr.com, Google Analytics does not accept it the way I want.

I have those urls:

```
/category/stuff382689,25090
```

and those:

```
/category/stuff382689,25090,,1
/category/stuff382689,25090,,2
...
```

But I only want to count the first one (without the double commas).
I tried this regex:

```
^.*stuff382689,.*?\d.+[^,,]$
```

But Google gives me all of them, including the double commas

Comment: Look at [this](https://regex101.com/r/rI3mL1/1). Is this what regexr.com tell you?

Comment: The first ones all look like [`^.*stuff382689,\d+$`](https://regex101.com/r/xB6jE5/1) or more different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This:

```
^.*stuff382689,(\w+)$
```

Tested in notepad++ and regex101.